# Is there a way to debug Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Angular and Firestore for my application. Unfortunately every CRUD tutorial I find doesn't cover the necessary rules to keep the application safe. I would only find rules for the previous solution by Google (not Firestore).

Now I did make the following rules for a create request:
Check if user ID matches the stored user ID. 
Check if the request size equals 5. 
Check if the request contains 5 fields with specific names. 
Check if the fields have the proper type (string, timestamp etc).

Somewhere, it breaks. I haven't touched it in a while but I really don't know where it starts to say "nope, won't let you in". There are no errors.

My question is, is there a way to debug what you exactly send and see what function doesn't let you in? If not, is there anyone that can provide example code of their CRUD rules? I would highly appreciate it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pretty much all of the FireStore calls have an *error* component which can be inspected to see what the nature of the error is. If you have a rule that denies writing to a collection/document, for example, that info will be returned in the error. When you state there are no error's, is that the error you are referring to or something else? Is there a piece of code that's isn't working? Can you include a snippet in the question along with the rules and FireStore structure? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there a way to debug what you exactly send and see what function doesn't let you in?

Firebase's security rules intentionally only give a very generic error message when a client tries to perform an operation that isn't allowed. The reason for this is that this information could otherwise be used by malicious users to try and work around your security rules.

The normal approach is to use the rules emulator in the Firebase console to test your read and write operations. This emulator tells you precisely what rules are allowing and rejecting a simulated operation.